# Where to set java options in jruby on rails?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

We are working on jruby on rails app. Want to set `JRUBY_OPTS` or `JAVA_OPTS`. 
I can easily use the `export` to set them on my machine, but I'd like these options to persist with the application.

Our application runs on tomcat in production can set options there in the config file.

Putting `export JAVA_OPTS` in the initializer file didn't work, seems like the options are set after application starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not "persist" such options within the app.

as you exported locally you might `export JAVA_OPTS` before Tomcat starts - its a JVM process that will read and set those opts for the VM, your app being deployed there has no control over most settings possible via `JAVA_OPTS` (memory, stack-size etc)